# LightGBM and Catboost are both installed but give ModuleNotFoundError when imported in Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, lightgbm, catboost

I have successfully installed the CatBoost and LightGbM modules using the command prompt. It gave me the message Successfully installed catboost-0.2.5 (I also previously tried another one). However, for both of them I have an identical error when I try to import both of them in a jupyter notebook:

```
import lightgbm as lgb
```

I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lightgbm'
```

and I get an identical error with CatBoost as well.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: let's talk in a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/174039) I made up for this discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174039/lightgbm), it turns out that the environment where your Jupyter notebooks run and the one where you have installed the packages are different.

Since `pip` reports both packages installed in your "main" environment (i.e. the one coming up when you simply open a Windows command prompt), what you should do is open Jupyter from the command prompt, as

```
jupyter notebook
```

and your packages will indeed be available for importing, as we confirmed indeed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!